# Chose file format when taking a screenshot with python

Tags: python, scripting, image

I'm trying to take a screenshot with Python using
[bpy.ops.screen.screenshot()](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_77_release/bpy.ops.screen.html#bpy.ops.screen.screenshot)

However I can't figure out how to chose what file format to save the image as. It will by default be saved as a PNG *(see screenshot below)*. Does anyone know if there would be a way to chose another file format *(such as jpeg, bmp etc.)* when saving a screenshot through python?

Thanks in advance! :)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently there is no way, you can only save directly to a PNG.

This is caused by the way the operator works, where the options to choose the image format are only initialized when the file-selector is used.

Comment: Ah, alright :/ Well, thanks for your answer!